# Ms Access - Join two tables and get the last record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables named Reefers and FilteredAlerts. I want to join these two tables.

How to get the last record of each Reefers where the Status = 'Loaded' and the GPSAlertype = 'Temperature'?

[image]

As you can see in the result, The ReeferNo R-3 is not showing because the GPSAlertType is not equal to Temperature. I'm using below code but always give me an error.

```
 SELECT
   r.ReeferNo,
   r.TransporterName,
   r.Status, 
   sub2.AlertDateTime,
   sub2.ReceivedDateTime,
   sub2.GPSAlertType,
   sub2.Temperature,
   sub2.Location
FROM
   Reefers AS r
   LEFT JOIN
   (
      SELECT
         sub1.ReeferNo,
         a2.AlertDateTime,
         a2.ReceivedDateTime,
         a2.GPSAlertType,
         a2.Temperature,
         a2.Location
     FROM
         (
             SELECT
                 a1.ReeferNo,
                 Max(a1.AlertDateTime) AS MaxOfAlertDateTime
             FROM FilteredAlerts AS a1
             WHERE a1.GPSAlertType='Temperatures' AND r.Status = 'Loaded'
             GROUP BY a1.ReeferNo
         ) AS sub1
         INNER JOIN FilteredAlerts AS a2
         ON
                (sub1.MaxOfAlertDateTime = a2.AlertDateTime)
            AND (sub1.ReeferNo = a2.ReeferNo)
     ) AS sub2
 ON r.ReeferNo = sub2.ReeferNo;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What kind of error do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
SELECT
    r2.ReeferNo,
    r2.TransporterName,
    r2.Status,
    a2.AlertDateTime,
    a2.ReceivedDateTime,
    a2.GPSAlertType,
    a2.Temperature,
    a2.Location
FROM ((SELECT r.ReeferNo, Max(a.AlertDateTime) as AlertDateTime
    FROM Reefers r LEFT JOIN FilteredAlerts a ON r.ReeferNo = a.ReeferNo
    WHERE
        r.Status="Loaded" AND 
        a.GPSAlertType='Temperature'
    GROUP BY r.ReeferNo
) s LEFT JOIN FilteredAlerts a2 ON 
    s.ReeferNo = a2.ReeferNo and
    s.AlertDateTime = a2.AlertDateTime
) INNER JOIN Reefers r2 ON s.ReeferNo = r2.ReeferNo
WHERE a2.GPSAlertType='Temperature' and
    r2.Status='Loaded';
```